# Use JSON On Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services

I have a Windows application that gets data from a webservice.

I need to use JSON to post or get data from the webservice.

What is the best way to do that? In the webservice and in the Windows application?

Please specify in details with a code sample because I am new to JSON.

Comment: If you can give more details, classes or samples of your code I'm sure we can offer a better detailed answer

Comment: i create a webservice only till now, i don't know how to send request using json from windows application and how to receive it in webservice and how to get respone to windows application from webservice

Answer (score 1):

Use [Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NewtonSoft.Json/)

You can download and install it from NuGet.

To use it you create a C# model that matches your Json and then call:

```
string json = "";
MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

and to Serialise:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyObject {});
```

See the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) for further examples and explanation.

Comment: after installing it, how can i use it, more details please?

Comment: There are a plethora of examples online.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Json.Net, you can use WCF as described in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON) article. WCF is a service framework provided by Microsoft as part of .Net.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give examples with out snippets of your classes and what you are trying to achieve.

However take a look at this function you could have in your webservice

```
using Newsoft.Json;

public JsonResult FunctionName(string JsonString)
{
    if (JsonString!= null)
    {
        YourObject YourObjectInstance = new YourObject ();

        try
        {
            YourObjectInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject >(JsonString);
           //do something with the data                

           // return a Json response of either your object or another object type
           return Json(YourObjectInstance, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new JsonResult();  //return empty JsonResult
        }
        }
        else
        {
            return new JsonResult();  //return empty JsonResult
        }

    }
}
```